# Display canvas live on multiple browsers

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, live

I am new to stack overflow, but I wantet to ask if someone knows a way I can display the same canvas on multiple browsers at the same time. Im working on a drawing app and I want to make it kind of like a little game. Some people should look at the given picture one person is drawing and guess what it should represent. So I need to find a way to let the users browser display the canvas another person is drawing on at the moment.

Comment: As i know, you should deploy a server and use some technique like PushStream or WebSocket...

Comment: you need to use websocket ( you can get started [here](http://socket.io/) )

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll try it :D